# sql query using left joins and where clause

Tags: mysql, sql, select, left-join

I have the following query

```
SELECT *
  FROM tbl_events AS event
       LEFT JOIN tbl_business_events AS bevent 
                 ON event.event_id = bevent.event_id 
       LEFT JOIN tbl_business_sector AS bsec 
                 ON event.event_id = bsec.event_id 
       LEFT JOIN tbl_sectors AS sector 
                 ON bsec.sector_id = sector.sector_id 
       LEFT JOIN tbl_event_location AS eloc 
                 ON event.event_id = eloc.event_id 
       LEFT JOIN tbl_locations AS location 
                 ON location.location_id = eloc.location_id 
 WHERE event.event_type = 1
```

which i use to pull out all the details of my event listings, this works but i now want to pull out the events profile picture from another table tbl_event_images. This table stores all the events images but has a field called is_profile_picture which determins if it is the profile pic or not (value is 0 for not and 1 if the image is the profile pic)

so i tried the following query to grab the event profile picture as well as the rest of the information with the following query

```
SELECT *
  FROM tbl_events AS event
       LEFT JOIN tbl_event_images AS eIMG 
                 ON event.event_id = eIMG.event_id
       LEFT JOIN tbl_business_events AS bevent 
                 ON event.event_id = bevent.event_id
       LEFT JOIN tbl_business_sector AS bsec 
                 ON event.event_id = bsec.event_id
       LEFT JOIN tbl_sectors AS sector 
                 ON bsec.sector_id = sector.sector_id
       LEFT JOIN tbl_event_location AS eloc 
                 ON event.event_id = eloc.event_id
       LEFT JOIN tbl_locations AS location 
                 ON location.location_id = eloc.location_id
 WHERE event.event_type =1
```

but this query returns a new row for each photo the event has in that table.

so i then tried to add another where clause to the above
    `AND eIMG.is_profile_picture =1`

but because not every listing has photos let alone a profile picture the above query only returns the events that have a profile picture.

how can i return 1 row for each event regardless if they have a profile pic or not? if they do then it will add the name of the image if it doesnt it sets it to NULL

Thanks
Luke

Comment: Just to clarify: 1) eIMG is the table that contains the picture, and 2) not all events have a picture? If you want to join to a table that may not contain a row that matches a join, you need to use an OUTER join instead.

Comment: @Alex A left join is an outer join.

Comment: @GoatCO sorry - I tend to explicitly specify inner vs outer so I was off track.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `WHERE` criteria add the `is_profile_picture` condition to your `JOIN` criteria:

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl_events AS event
LEFT JOIN tbl_event_images AS eIMG 
   ON   event.event_id = eIMG.event_id 
    AND eIMG.is_profile_picture =1
LEFT JOIN tbl_business_events AS bevent 
   ON event.event_id = bevent.event_id
LEFT JOIN tbl_business_sector AS bsec 
   ON event.event_id = bsec.event_id
LEFT JOIN tbl_sectors AS sector 
   ON bsec.sector_id = sector.sector_id
LEFT JOIN tbl_event_location AS eloc 
   ON event.event_id = eloc.event_id
LEFT JOIN tbl_locations AS location 
   ON location.location_id = eloc.location_id
WHERE event.event_type =1
```

`WHERE` filters all results, and in this case effectively negates your use of `LEFT JOIN`.  Adding to the `JOIN` criteria itself means only some pictures will join, but all the results of your original query will still be returned.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl_events AS event
LEFT JOIN tbl_event_images AS eIMG ( ON event.event_id = eIMG.event_id AND  eIMG.is_profile_picture = 1 )
LEFT JOIN tbl_business_events AS bevent ON event.event_id = bevent.event_id
LEFT JOIN tbl_business_sector AS bsec ON event.event_id = bsec.event_id
LEFT JOIN tbl_sectors AS sector ON bsec.sector_id = sector.sector_id
LEFT JOIN tbl_event_location AS eloc ON event.event_id = eloc.event_id
LEFT JOIN tbl_locations AS location ON location.location_id = eloc.location_id
WHERE event.event_type =1
```